# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I made code to try a users activity on my forum, and when I add in this line

```
$cat_id = $db->fetch("SELECT name FROM " . $prefix . "_categories WHERE id =" . mysql_real_escape_string($forum_data['cat_id']));
$page_title_pro = ' > ' . $system->present($cat_id['name']) . ' > ' . $system->present($forum_data['name']) . '';
```

I get

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Treasures > Contests' WHERE id = '2'' at line 1
```

I am assuming that the 2 is my user id, and in the footer, I have this :

```
$db->query("UPDATE accounts SET flocation = '$session_location', page = '$page_title_pro'  WHERE id = '$id';");
```

I can't seem to find the error, and every goes back to normal when i take the cat_id out, but then i can't use the current activity for the profiles. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `$prefix` content?

Comment: The value you are retrieving has a ' in it. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use **near 's Treasures** > Contests' WHERE id = '2'' at line 1. It's the data of `name` that is messing it up.

Comment: $prefix is the table prefix, which is forum   @MarioWenig: I can't find that in any lines of my codes     It's the footer code, but how do i change it?

Comment: @Malik it's in the value of `$page_title_pro`, you need to escape it. if you're using `PDO` use prepared statements.

Comment: It's not in your code, it's the value that gets returned. Example: Lets say your name returns as **Giligan's Island** the single quote breaks your query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem with your update syntax. The problem is with the values you want to set on specific column that contains single quote which causes to break your update syntax. You need to escape the single quotes in the value before passing it on the query. One possible way is by using

**mysql_real_escape_string**

```
$val1 = mysql_real_escape_string($session_location);
$val2 = mysql_real_escape_string($page_title_pro);
$val3 = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$db->query("UPDATE accounts SET flocation = '$val1', page = '$val2'  WHERE id = '$val3'");
```

Another (**the PREFERRED one**) is by using `PreparedStatements` (`PDO` or `MySQLi` extensions) you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

mysql_real_escape_string your input value for the Update query, its `$page_title_pro` from the previous query that has a **'** in it.